# Why doesn't Cauchy-Schwarz in $\mathbb{R}^n$ generalize to exponents $k>2$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products

Given $(x_i)_{i=1}^n, (y_i)_{i=1}^n \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Notable_special_cases) asserts $$\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \right)^2.$$

Conspicuously absent from the Wikipedia page is a claim that $$\left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i \right)^k \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^k \right)$$ holds for $k>2$, which makes me think it's untrue (and similarly for the same formula with absolute value signs around the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s).  Indeed, we can find random counter-examples on a computer.

*Question*: Why doesn't Cauchy-Schwarz in $\mathbb{R}^n$ generalize to exponents $k>2$?

Can we gain any insight into why it works for $k=2$ but not for $k>2$?

Comment: A generalization of CS inequality to $k \neq 2$ is Holder's inequality. I don't know it answers your question though...

Comment: This is a good question to ask yourself. As roger said, Holder's inequality is the generalization to Cauchy-Schwarz (check it out on Wikipedia). The case $p = 2$ satisfies the parallelogram law $\|f + g\|^2_2 + \|f-g\|_2^2 = 2(\|f\|_2^2 + \|g\|_2^2)$, which is so named as reflecting a property of Euclidean space. The function space $L^p$ (you'll have to look it up for Holder's) for $p = 2$ has an inner product iff the paral. law is satisfied. You might argue that CS is a reflection of Euclidean space. Alternatively, draw the set $\{ x : \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p = 1\}$ for various $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives an optimal comparison between the Euclidian inner product and the Euclidian norm. The generalization would compare the latter with the $\ell_k$-norm for $k\gt 2$. Since $\mathbb R^n$ is finite dimensional, we know that there is $C_n$ such that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$,
$$|\langle x,y\rangle|\leqslant C_n\lVert x\rVert_{\ell_k}\cdot \lVert y\rVert_{\ell_k},$$
but taking $x=y=(1,\dots,1)^t$, we can see that $n^{k-2}\leqslant C_n$, so we cannot choose $C_n=1$.

Comment: Nice explanation; thank you!

Comment: You are welcome!