# Is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality generalizable to any natural power $ p \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I was wondering if we let $ p $ be a natural number, would the following hold ?

$$ 
\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_ky_k \right)^p \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k^p\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_k^p
$$

I believe it should. If we reformulate this in terms of dot product, we would have:

$$ 
\Vert \vec{x}\cdot \vec{y} \Vert^p \leq \Vert \vec{x} \Vert^p \cdot  \Vert \vec{y} \Vert^p
$$

which 'seems' true.

Please notify if anything isn't clear or doesn't comply with the rules.

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484872/why-doesnt-cauchy-schwarz-in-mathbbrn-generalize-to-exponents-k2.

Comment: How does it “seem” true or why do you “believe it should”?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for the reference. Wrong intuition I guess

Comment: It *is* true for $0 < p \le 2$ though ...